# TextView FILL_PARENT doesn't work

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

I want to make that TextView fill parent but my code doesn't work.

Here is my code:

```
TableLayout tableLayout = new TableLayout(this);

    TableRow.LayoutParams tableRowParams = new TableRow.LayoutParams();
    TableRow.LayoutParams param = new TableRow.LayoutParams();

    tableRowParams.setMargins(1, 1, 1, 1);
    param.span = 2;
    param.setMargins(1, 1, 1, 1);

    int trainIndex = 0;
    int stationIndex = 1;


    for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++){
        TableRow row = new TableRow(this);

        if(i == 0){
            TextView text = new TextView(this);

            text.setText("Way");
            text.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
            text.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            row.addView(text, tableRowParams);

            for(int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
                TextView text1 = new TextView(this);

                text1.setText(getInfo(0, stationIndex));
                text1.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
                row.addView(text1, param);
                stationIndex++;
            }
        }else {

            for (int j = 0; j <= 8; j++) {
                TextView text = new TextView(this);


                if(j == 0){
                    text.setText(getInfo(1,trainIndex));
                    text.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
                    row.addView(text, tableRowParams);
                    trainIndex++;
                }else {
                    text.setText("   train  " + j);
                    text.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
                    row.addView(text, tableRowParams);
                }
            }
        }
        tableLayout.addView(row);
    }

    setContentView(tableLayout);
```

When I apply layout params to textview it doesn't work and when text isn't very long it causes white space in cells, I want that all cells have grey background.

Here is the sample how it looks:
[image]

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to set LayoutParams for the TextView. By default is uses WRAP_CONTENT for both width and height.

Also, use MATCH_PARENT instead of FILL_PARENT

**EDIT**

Try this:

```
TableRow row = new TableRow(this);
TextView text = new TextView(this);
text.setText("Way");
text.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
text.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
row.addView(text);
```

Comment: I'm sorry, actually I want that my TextView match_parent.

Comment: That is the problem. Your TextView is not match_parent by default, and you don't change it in the code.
Check my edit.

Comment: still nothing, here is this text view in XML:                                               <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:text="Київ - Ніжин"
                android:id="@+id/textView"
                android:allowUndo="false"
                android:background="#dfdcdc"
                android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textSize="15sp" />

Comment: Are you adding the TableRow to the table?

Comment: Yes. I have created the table layout, than table row and text view for row and now I want that text view match_parent.

Comment: What exactly is not working? Does the TableRow appear?

Comment: Yes. Table with TableRow and TextView appear but TextView doesn't match_parent and it causes a blank space in cell.

Comment: Can you edit the question and post the image how it looks now and how you want it to look?

Comment: Can you post a screenshot?

Comment: I posted.But I drew it on Paint, because I don't know how to make a screenshot on phone.

Comment: Try to set specific value to the height, instead of MATCH_PARENT

Answer (score 0):

Be sure that your container has the `FILL_PARENT` property

```
TableLayout tableLayout = new TableLayout(this);
tableLayout.setStretchAllColumns(true);
tableLayout.setLayoutParams(new TableLayout.LayoutParams(TableLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, TableLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
```